# Hair color transformation

Tags: animation

I am working in blender and planning to create a character where the hair changes from black to white. I want to make an animated video which shows the change happens from the beginning of the hair, gradually to the end. I took the idea from the Disney animated movie, Tangled, when Rapunzel’s hair glows in a gradual way.Thanks for every help;))

Comment: This can be easily achieved, but any techniques are largely dependent on what type of hair geometry you have, which you never state. Are you using particles? Strands? Mesh hair? Bezier Curves? Are they correctly UV mapped? Please edit your question and provide more details

Comment: Yeah, we need a LOT more information :)

Comment: I haven’t made it yet. Just want to know what type of hair allows to make the transformation animation of the color.what type of hair geometry hair is most recommend. I am beginner on blender

Comment: It’s like the animation Disney movie tangled which the character’s hair change to shiny hair from up to down